# How do I extract timestamp and keywords from logs?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have wifi logs that I need to clean and parse. I want to take the timestamp and specific keywords, then save them to a new file. I am currently using this to clean the output file, then save the specific logs that contain Assoc Success to the output.txt file.

```
open("output.txt", "w").close()
with open("SampleLogs.txt", "r") as in_file, open("output.txt", "w") as out_file:
    for line in in_file.readlines():
        if "Assoc success" in line:
            out_file.write(line)
```

The logs now look like this:

> Sep 16 23:59:58 RU3109-2-A7240-2 stm[7119]: <501119> <7119>    Assoc success @ 23:59:58.982251: 04:8d:6d:ec:77:23: AP 10.47.89.24-47:3a:e8:b5:e1:c1-EXT-St130A-AP365-1

What is the best way to extract only the timestamp (Sep 16 23:59:58) and the keyword (RU3109)?

Comment: Why the pandas tag? There is no pandas usage here.

Comment: I am using pandas to import these logs into dataframes, but that is not listed here. I probably should have left out the pandas tag.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this way can help you.

```py
split_list = line.split()
timestamp = " ".join(split_list[:3])
keyword = split_list[3].split("-")[0]
```